# Flutter website has blue parts around app on iPhone

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Well this might not be very well explained in the title, but the screen speaks by itself: [phone screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQYbq.png)

I want to get rid of the blue things on the top and bottom of the app. The color is the exact same of the default appbar in a new project so I guess it has something to do with the MaterialApp in main.dart and a theme color inside of it, I just can't find which one. Also this appears only on Safari, and not on the google app. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I finally got it to work, the problem was coming from the fact that I used containers as backgrounds, and not scaffolds. By putting a scaffold in each class, and determining it's background color to the one I wanted, it solved the problem.

Comment: You can set the colors yourself. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683403

Comment: @Rahul this would imply using meta tag, but this is in CSS, and after a little bit of search it seems hard to do in flutter. But safari doesnt pick the color randomly, and it's the blue color that we are used to in flutter, so don't you think that safari recognises a color in the code that is specified somewhere, and that I could change?

Comment: flutter code is transformed into js/css by the compiler. You can go to web folder generated and put the meta tag directly.

Comment: @Rahul oh thanks didnt know that, I'll try this then!

Answer (score 0):

you can use your color code. Please use this link to make your MaterialColor.
https://maketintsandshades.com/#451088

you have to add primarySwatch color in your MaterialApp ThemeData. Like this.

```
theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: myGreyColor,
    ),    

static const MaterialColor myGreyColor = MaterialColor(
    0xFF9E9E9E,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      100: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      200: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
      300: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
      350: Color(0xFFD6D6D6), // only for raised button while pressed in light theme
      400: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
      500: Color(0xFF9E9E9E),
      600: Color(0xFF757575),
      700: Color(0xFF616161),
      800: Color(0xFF424242),
      850: Color(0xFF303030), // only for background color in dark theme
      900: Color(0xFF212121),
    },
  )
```